# Preventing same application running at same time but based on input parameter

Tags: c#, mutex

I want to prevent the instance running for the specific parameter entered from the command line. I want to allow multiple instances running if they all take different parameters. Here is my code snippet trying to implement this:

```
private static readonly Mutex SingletonA = new Mutex(true, "A");
private static readonly Mutex SingletonB = new Mutex(true, "B");

var arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

if(arguments[1]=="A" && !SingletonA.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) return; //end the process
if(arguments[1]=="B" && !SingletonB.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) return; //end the process
```

However I noticed both SingletonA and SingletonB will be false if there is a running instance.

Is there a way to implement it?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of the process each launched from the CLI separately, or you are using the CLI to pass commands to the same process each time?

Comment: @JonAdams look at the code `var arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`

Comment: @JonAdams Separately. The program will be executed like `prog.exe A`, `prog.exe B`

Answer (score -1):

Please consider that this answer only illustrate the idea, and does not contain code ready for usage:

```
private static Mutex Singleton = null;
...
var arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var mutexName = arguments[1];

Singleton = new Mutex(false, mutexName);

if(!Singleton.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) return; //end the process
```

or

```
private static Mutex Singleton = null;
...
var arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var mutexName = arguments[1];
var isCreated = false;

Singleton = new Mutex(true, mutexName, isCreated);

if (!isCreated)
  Environment.Exit(1); //end the process
```

Comment: Saw minuses, reviewed my code and make Mutex unowned till the first WaitOne call. But still, the idea is the same - use input parameter (directly or indirectly) as a Mutex name. Can someone stop and explain where is the problem with this approach (except for not supporting mindless copy-pasters)

Comment: I think after I changed it to `new Mutex(true, mutexName);`, your code seems to work.

Comment: Based on MSDN [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Mutex__ctor_System_Boolean_) (Remarks) it is recommended to use false. As an alternative approach you can use constructor with three parameters `Mutex(Boolean, string, boolean)` this way `var mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out iscreated); if (!iscreated) Environment.Exit(1);`. I will update my answer to reflect this

Answer (score -1):

Per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Mutex__ctor_System_Boolean_System_String_) for that constructor (emphasis mine):

> If name is not null and initiallyOwned is true, the calling thread owns the mutex only if the named system mutex was created as a result of this call. **Since there is no mechanism for determining whether the named system mutex was created, it is better to specify false for initiallyOwned when calling this constructor overload.** You can use the Mutex(Boolean, String, Boolean) constructor if you need to determine initial ownership.

Change the call to pass in false for the ownership parameter, and you should be all set.

```
private static readonly Mutex SingletonA = new Mutex(
    false, 
    "A");
private static readonly Mutex SingletonB = new Mutex(
    false,
    "B");
```

(Though this example probably isn't super useful to others, since the first process takes both the Mutex singletons immediately, and there is no context around how long it holds them, why, or when or how the process exits.)